# wordcloud2: shape covers words

Tags: r, wordcloud2

I tried to plot a wordcloud with `wordcloud2`. As long as I just try to plot the words, everything works fine, but as soon as I try to shape the wordcloud with `figPath`/`wordcloud2::lettercloud` something goes wrong. To see the output, I have to run the function twice/reload it (I think this is a bug that has already been reported and discussed)

Additionally in my case it seems like I just plot the shape without the words ...

```
dat <- dplyr::tibble(word=c("A","B","C","D"),
                     n=c(10,1,50,12))
# works fine
wordcloud2::wordcloud2(dat)
# here I just see the shape
wordcloud2::wordcloud2(dat,figPath="data/test_shape.jpg")
# here I just see the letter
wordcloud2::letterCloud(dat,word="R")
```

[image]

Comment: not even the example works to me `library(wordcloud2);example(letterCloud)`. I have `R 4.0.2`

Comment: same here and I have R 3.6.3

Comment: Try: wordcloud2(demoFreq)  - it will appear in the Viewer not in the plot window

Comment: For the code of sambold to work you have to have a jpg picture in this path: figPath="data/test_shape.jpg"

Comment: true, I forgot to mention that. But I think that was not the issue, as it seems that example(letterCloud) does not work either.

Comment: @Steffen Moritz, the normal wordcloud2 function works perfectly. But as soon as you use shapes there seems to be a problem

Comment: I tried this once, wordcloud worked (also with argument shape). But letterCloud or even figPath did not work. (maybe not implemented yet?)

Comment: hm. strange. I also tried ggwordcloud::ggwordcloud2 (which should mimic wordcloud2), but as soon as you use shapes, it throws an error. Anyways ... wordclouds are bad practice, so I guess I should move on :D